# is there any log for system exceptions

Tags: c#, windows, exception

If I am moving a folder from one location to another location. is there any log maintains in system for this. or if moving or copying failed then is there any error log maintained by windows itself.

thanks in advance...

Comment: you could try looking in windows event viewer

Comment: There is no logging of copies. An error may cause an entry to be made in the Windows Event Log.

Comment: XY problem. What are you really trying to accomplish?